# PHP query string with variables in it not working

Tags: php, mysql

When I build a query string using variables in PHP, it does not seem to be working. My current query is:

```
$u = "admin";
$hash = password_hash("password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$set_login = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ({$u}, {$hash})";
```

*I am executing the query further down in the script

If I replace `{$u}` with the string literal it represents, and replace `{$hash}` with just a string literal for a password, such as `password`, the query works fine. However, when I introduce variables that is when it breaks. I've tried breaking up the query string and using the concatenation operator:

```
$set_login = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ( " . $u . ", " . $hash . ")";
```

This did not work either. I then thought it might be something with the hash, so I modified the code to (for testing):

```
$u = "admin";
$p = "password";
$set_login = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ({$u}, {$p})";
```

This did not work either.

Comment: use prepared statements instead

Comment: This is really bad approach in general, you should use **prepared statements**. BUT, try adding **quotes** to the query. Something like `"INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('{$u}', '{$hash}')";`

Comment: Make sure the column for the password is at least 60 characters or you will have problems when trying to verify passwords.

Comment: You need to stop this bad habit of not accepting answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), it's very simple.

here's how you will do it with prepared statements

**mysqli**

```
<?php
$u = "admin";
$hash = password_hash("password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$set_login = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)";
$query = $ConnectionString->prepare($set_login);
$query->bind_param("ss",$u,$hash);

if($query){
    echo "success";
}else{

    error_log("error".$ConnectionString->error);
}

?>
```

**PDO**

```
<?php
$u    = "admin";
$hash = password_hash("password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$query = $ConnectionString->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)")->execute(array($u,$hash));

if ($query) {
    echo "success";
} else {

    error_log("error" . $ConnectionString->errorInfo());
}

?>
```

Some useful resources.

[PDO Connection](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)
[PDO Tutorials](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)
[Mysqli Prepared](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

> NB: AS Jay have indicated in his comment make sure your password field
>   size in the database is at least 60 Characters

In your query the problem is that you did not wrapper the strings around quotes

Your query should be:

```
$set_login = "INSERT INTO admin (uname, upass) VALUES ('{$u}', '{$hash}')";
```

But this is not the best recommended way of doing quires, you should use one of the methods above using prepared statements.

Here's why you should : 
[Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('{$u}', '{$hash}')
```

Don't forget to wrap string with a quotation mark

But as mentioned in comments, it's bad idea to put data directly, use prepared statements